# Exponent of wreath product

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a wreath product of $H$ and $K$. We denote $exp(G)$ the exponent of $G$. Then $exp(G)$ divide $exp(H)exp(K)$. Is $exp(G)=exp(H)exp(K)$?

Comment: Yes it's true. Indeed, this reduces immediately to the case $H=C(p^k)$, $K=C(p^n)$, where $C(m)$ is cyclic of order $m$. Since $H\wr K$ contains any extension $H$-by-$K$, in particular in contains $C(p^{k+n})$.

Comment: @YCor, is the $p$ a prime number?

Comment: My answer is a copy of this comment, where I added this kind of details.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's true (with both restricted and unrestricted wreath products, in case you also deal with infinite groups). Indeed it is enough to prove it when, denoting $C(m)=\mathbf{Z}/m\mathbf{Z}$, the case of $H=C(p^k)$ and $K=C(p^n)$ when $p$ is prime. Recall that the unrestricted wreath product $H\wr K$ always contains any extension $H$-by-$K$. Hence $C(p^k)\wr C(p^n)$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $C(p^{n+k})$.

Comment: this page (http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_semidirect_product_may_be_strictly_greater_than_lcm_of_exponents) says that exponent of semidirect product may be strictly greater than lcm of exponents. Doesn't it conflict with what you are saying?

Comment: No because I said it's the product, not the lcm

Comment: so can we say that the exponent of any semidirect product is strictly the product of the exponents of the two groups? Is we can is there any proof for that?

Comment: I don't know what you call "is strictly". I don't understand your statement. I proved something precise, with no claim about general semidirect products.

Comment: I should have been clearer. Let me go one step back. I assume $H=C(p^k)$ means the exponent of $H$ is $k$ and similarly the exponent of $K$ is $n$. Now how would I know that there is not an element in $C(p^k)\wr C(p^n)$ whose order is not more than the exponent of $C(p^{n+k})$?

Comment: In any extension $G$ of a normal subgroup $N$ by a quotient group $Q$, if $n$ and $q$ are the exponents of $N$ and $Q$, then the exponent of $G$ divides $nq$. This is immediate.